# If specific text exists in text file

Tags: php

I want to track which sites are using my theme. And I added a code to my theme which is `<img src="http://example.com/callback.php">` and my callback.php file content is

```
<?php
    if(!$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']){
        echo "No direct access!";
    } else {
        $logfile= 'log.txt';
        if(is_writable($logfile)) {
            $referer = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
            $referer = $referer['host'];
            $fp = fopen($logfile, "a");
            fwrite($fp, $referer);
            fwrite($fp, "\n");
            fclose($fp); 
        } else {
            echo "log.txt is not writable";
        }
    }
?>
```

But it writes same domain every page load. I want to check domain name first and if domain name is in the text file it should not add it.

Comment: `strpos` is what you need.

Comment: I tried this `$check = strpos($logfile, $referer);
if ($check === false) {
fwrite($fp, $referer);
fwrite($fp, "\n");
fclose($fp); }`

But it didnt work, am I doing mistake ?

Comment: The problem with `strpos()` is the following scenario: 1) referrer from `example.com`, 2) referrer from `example.co`. It will never write `example.co` to the log. Neither will `ple.com` (and so forth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?php
    if(!$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']){
        echo "No direct access!";
        exit();
    } else {
        $logfile= 'log.txt';
        if(is_writable($logfile)) {
            $referer = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
            $referer = $referer['host'];
            $fp = fopen($logfile, "a+");
            $flag=false;
            while(!feof($fp)){
                if(trim(fgets($fp)) === trim($referer))
                $flag=true;
            }
            if(!$flag){
                fwrite($fp, $referer);
                fwrite($fp, "\r\n");
            }
            fclose($fp);
        } else {
            echo "log.txt is not writable";
            exit();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer Rashid ! Is strtpos() cause some problems which are @localheinz commented on the first answer? I mean is there any difference between your code and  localheinz's one?

Comment: Thank you again Rashid. Is there any difference between your code localheinz's code?  Or it is just different logic?

Comment: Yes, It is fully different from localheinz's code, And also different logic.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php

if (!$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) {
    echo "No direct access!";

    exit();
} 

$logfile= 'log.txt';

if (!is_writable($logfile)) {
    echo "log.txt is not writable";

    exit();
} 

$referer = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
$host = $referer['host'];

$hosts = file($logfile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

if (in_array($host, $hosts)) {
    exit();
}

$handle = fopen($logfile, "a");

fwrite($handle, $host);
fwrite($handle, "\n");

fclose($handle);
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: Thank you so much it didnt work at first time. There were 2 parentheses mistake in your code and I fixed it. Also I edited your answer code as well.
By the way, In your opinion, is this code causes efficiency problem on hosts? Can it decelerate the websites?